# error to load main class for sqoop after successful instalation

Tags: windows, hadoop, installation, sqoop

OS: Windows 10

Sqoop Version: 1.4.7

Hadoop Version: 2.9.2

Hi after installing Sqoop on win 10 following the instructions from
https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/sqoop-how-to-install-in-5-steps-in-windows-10-ca2f17e11e75

i then try to check the install using the "sqoop version" command, but all i get is following error:

it fails:

C:\Users\iamme>sqoop version

Warning: HBASE_HOME and HBASE_VERSION not set.

Warning: HCAT_HOME not set

Warning: HCATALOG_HOME does not exist HCatalog imports will fail.

Please set HCATALOG_HOME to the root of your HCatalog installation.

Warning: ACCUMULO_HOME not set.

Warning: ZOOKEEPER_HOME not set.

Warning: HBASE_HOME does not exist HBase imports will fail.

Please set HBASE_HOME to the root of your HBase installation.

Warning: ACCUMULO_HOME does not exist Accumulo imports will fail.

Please set ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.

Warning: ZOOKEEPER_HOME does not exist Accumulo imports will fail.

Please set ZOOKEEPER_HOME to the root of your Zookeeper installation.

Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop

I checked all Hadoop and Sqoop ENV Variables, and they seem to be fine.
Any clue what might be wrong?

Best Regards,
R.S.

Comment: Apache Sqoop was moved into the Apache Attic nearly a year ago now - https://attic.apache.org/projects/sqoop.html. Are you sure it's the right project for your needs?

Comment: Many of the Sqoop contributors went to work on Streamsets, which is similar to Apache Nifi. Both of which are far more feature rich and easier to setup than Sqoop